# How to select what in some string and not exist in datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, linq, datatable

If i have a datatable `dt` like that :

```
emp_num 

462

31

66
```

and i have a string of numbers concatenated by comma like that :

```
string res = "52,31,78,2312,99"
```

---

Expected result :

```
52,78,2312,99
```

How to select what in `res` and not in `dt` through linq ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: this's set of numbers i want what exist in this string (`res`)and not exist in the datatable

Comment: Why do you want to do it with linq?

Comment: @Reniuz:if there's some simple way instead of looping ,it will be nice

Comment: I really like the question like @Reniuz, which doesn't carry any sense..  you should focus on the question rather then cross question untill-unless its really needed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `Split` then use `Except`, i assume the column's type is `int`:

```
IEnumerable<int> empNums = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("emp_num"));
IEnumerable<int> resNums = res.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
IEnumerable<int> inResButNotInTable = resNums.Except(empNums);
```

You can use a `foreach` or another method that materializes the query to a collection like `ToList`.

Comment: I use .net 3.5 is there something wrong `int.Parse`build error and can't String[] doesn't have definition for Select 
and can't find `Except`

Comment: `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @just_name: you have to add `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I use `using System.Linq` but i get
The type arguments for method `'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnum‌​erable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @just_name: i have tested the code with your datatable and with .NET 3.5, it works for me.

Comment: the error here `IEnumerable<int> resNums = res.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);`

Comment: @just_name: so can you use LINQ at all? `res.Split(',')` returns a `string[]` which  implements `IEnumerable<string>`, therefore you can use LINQ. You could rewrite it to use  a lambda instead of the method directly, but i doubt that this solves the issue: `IEnumerable<int> resNums = res.Split(',').Select(str => int.Parse(str));`

Answer (score 1):

whats about this?? if `dt` stores the emp_num as string..

```
(res.Split(','))
     .Where(c => dt.AsEnumerable().Count(c2 => c2.Field<string>("emp_num") == c)==0)
     .ToList();
```

if `dt` stores the **emp_num** as `int`

```
(res.Split(','))
     .Where(c => dt.AsEnumerable().Count(c2 => c2.Field<int>("emp_num") == int.Parse(c.Trim()))==0)
     .ToList();
```